# Shopify: how to use Bing Conversion Tracking (UET) on checkout?

Tags: shopify, bing, event-tracking

I have a question about how to use Bing Conversion Tracking (UET) on checkout?

I have created a new UET tag, inserted code into shopify (Online Store > Preferences >Additional Google Analytics JavaScript) and it is working fine except checkout page!

I see next errors in the console:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyY1J.png)
Can someone help me and show the correct way how to insert bing tracking on the checkout?
Or describe why these errors usually occur? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your UET tag to your thank you page

1. In your Shopify account, go to Settings > Checkout.
2. the Additional scripts section, paste the UET tag and then click Save.
   [image]

Comment: Yes, I did it, but it adds the script to the success page. I mean the script does not work on the checkout itself (address / payment steps)

Comment: I don't think shopify will allow you to add any script to checkout page itself unless you are using their Plus plan.  where you have tried to put your script ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Bhargav Kaklotara for for pointing out that the tag works with the ORDER STATUS page.  If you want to check if it works, simply go into an order, click on More Actions on the top right handside, and select View Order Status Page.  You will see that the UET tag helper confirms the tag is installed properly (if you have added it to the check out page, which can be done from the Shopify Settings menu => check out => scroll all the way down to Order status page - Add tracking scripts and other customizations - Additional scripts.

There is a special bit of code to add on top of your tag if you want to include taxes and shipping https://help.ads.microsoft.com/#apex/ads/en/56901/-1.

Comment: what's the point of linking to https://www.nauradika.com/ ?

Comment: This looks like it contains some useful information, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt here and remove it for you this time, but please leave unrelated links out of posts in the future.